# SQL Is this LEFT JOIN equivalent to the Minus

Tags: sql

I am trying to write the equivalent left join to this minus operation in SQL
here is the original code

```
SELECT 
 R,
 D,
 S,
 T,
 C,
 E
FROM FIRST_TABLE MINUS

SELECT
 R,
 D,
 S,
 T,
 C,
 E
FROM SECOND_TABLE`;
```

I am converting a piece of code from a minus to a left outter join (only taking the records from the left table)
Here is the code I wrote

```
SELECT 
     I.R
    ,I.D
    ,I.S
    ,I.T
    ,I.C
    ,I.E
FROM      FIRST_TABLE   AS I 
LEFT JOIN SECOND_TABLE  AS W
ON  
I.R     = W.R       AND 
I.D     = W.D       AND 
I.S     = W.S       AND 
I.T     = W.T       AND 
I.C     = W.C       AND 
I.E     = W.E
WHERE 
W.R     IS NULL AND 
W.D     IS NULL AND 
W.S     IS NULL AND 
W.T     IS NULL AND 
W.C     IS NULL AND 
W.E     IS NULL;
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: where is the javascript part?

Comment: basically the code which you wrote should work. But probably it could be nice to add ifnull to join columns ifnull(I.R,'X') = ifnull(W.R,'X') to make sure that you wont miss null values.

Comment: `MINUS` is Oracle's version of the SQL standard`s `EXCEPT` operator. Can't you just use `EXCEPT` instead?